# Open a specific product tab programmatically in a Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, product

I am using woocommerce. After submission of certain form I want to send it to product page with opening a certain tab, here "Addition Information" tab...

How can I achieve this ?

I have tried url like 'WEBSITE/product/product-3/#tab-additional_information'

But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**

Yes this is possible with a little bit of javascript and jQuery embedded code in a custom php function hooked in **`wp_footer`** action hook.

The call will be made in the url like: **`WEBSITE/product/product-3/?tab=additional_information`**

Here is that function code:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_reordering_product_tabs_action' );
function custom_reordering_product_tabs_action() {
     // Only in single product pages and a specific url (using GET method) 
    if( isset( $_GET['tab'] ) && is_product()) :
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('ul.tabs.wc-tabs > li.active').removeClass("active");
                $('div#tab-description').hide();
                $('ul.tabs.wc-tabs > li.<?php echo $_GET['tab']; ?>_tab').addClass("active");
                $('div#tab-<?php echo $_GET['tab']; ?>').show();
            }, 500);
        })(jQuery);
        </script>
        <?php
    endif;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works

---

May be what you can do instead of open a product tab automatically, is **to reorder** in 1st position **automatically that tab** trough **`$_GET`** method (adding a variable in the url).

The call in your url will need to be like: **`WEBSITE/product/product-3/?tab=additional_information`**

You will be able to do it with that custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_product_tabs`** filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'custom_reordering_product_tabs_action', 98 );
function custom_reordering_product_tabs_action( $tabs ) {
    if( empty( $_GET['tab'] ) ) return $tabs;

    $tabs[$_GET['tab']]['priority'] = 2;

    return $tabs;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works

Comment: Thanks for the reply Loic, But I would not like to move/change tab position.

Comment: @Alice Ok I got it working as you want this time, with a bit of javascript/jQuery… Please check it. Thanks

Comment: # Alice Thanks. This was not so easy, as there is already multiple active WooCommerce JS events interfering.

Comment: @Alice I am relatively new to WooCommerce as I have really started 2 years ago with version 2.5 and I have been just like you not so far away. Each of us have some different valuable skills in evolution…